# How to make Servlet recognize caller JSP and session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dygraphs

I am building a simple WebApplication using servlets. I am a beginner but have tried to learn the most of this technology. There is something I cannot figure out. One of my servlets is the useful BalusC FileServlet

```
http://balusc.blogspot.mx/2007/07/fileservlet.html
```

It responds to GET requests with the required file, nice and clean.

I use this FileServlet to serve CSV files for a Dygraph

```
http://dygraphs.com/
```

I have two types of users: guests and admins. Guests should be able to SEE the graph BUT NOT be able to DOWNLOAD the CSV file. Admins should be able to do both.

The fileServlet responds to URL-patterns as: file/* (* is the filename), and it is VERY convenient as the Dygraph reads for a file as specified in an URL.

There is a loginServlet built within this webapp, and I want to be able to avoid the fileservlet to GIVE the file if the user just copy-pastes the URL that is given for the Dygraph. The FileServlet is already capable of getting the session and loggeduser from that session, but I don't know how to detect what was the page that called the GET method. I want the fileservlet to serve the file ONLY when called from within the JSP code, and not from the browser's address bar.

Let me explain a bit:

I mean -as a guest user- the following Javascript code should display the graph (the FileServlet serves the file)

```
<div id="graphdiv2" style="width:640px; height:480px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
g2 = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
"${messages.rutacsv}", // path to CSV file
{
rollPeriod: 10,
showRoller: true
}
);
</script>            
</div>
```

The variable:
"${messages.rutacsv}" gets replaced by the servlet for something that looks like this:

"file/2012-04-20_1.csv"

So the Dygraph loads the file nicely and plots the lines.

BUT, I want the FileServlet to be able to detect when the user copypastes this URL after the ContextName and block it, so only the Dygraph can download the file.

For example, if the user types in his browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/file/2012-04-20_1.csv
```

It shouldn't be able to download it. Only admins should be able to.

NOW, I am thinking that maybe I should implement the FileServlet so it has to be called with another URL pattern or with a POST method so a simple user copy-pasta can't get past the "origining-JSP" check.

BTW, I'm coming back from trying with Struts2, which is by far too complicated for this application. I abandoned it for convenience and ease of development with simple servlets and JSPs.

Comment: Looks like what you need is Servlet Filter, that checks url and current user role and allows direct download for admins only. For other requests just return 404 or send redirect to JSP.

Comment: Ok, but I don't think I have implemented user roles. I only do session.setAttribute("logonuser","username") on the session. I guess I have to do that additional work... don't I?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If any logged in user may direct-download, then you may check if `logonuser` attribute is present in session, else redirect to login servlet for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm) to check a user role. That's, before the any important action is necessary to check whether the user has a right to this action. This is the task servlet filter.

You must implement the method `doFilter()` in your class extending `javax.servlet.Filter` as follows:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws   IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    String currentRole = (String) session.getAttribute("userRole");

    if ("admin".equals(currentRole)) {
         successRedirect(); 
    } else {
         failRedirect();
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And don't forget map this filter to the needed address in the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CheckRightAccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>yourproject.CheckRightAccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CheckRightAccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.csv</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Do I have to implement that "task roles" on my own? It sounds like I should first implement them and then get to the Servlet Filter. I am now storing the username for the session, and then the FileServlet checks if it is named "admin", just that.

Comment: You need to set a variable `userRole` in session: `session.setAttribute(userRole,"nameUserRole")`. This action must be taken after a user has successfully passed the stage of authorization. So in order by the received information it was clear what role should is assigned him

Comment: Ok, now. Let's say I've implemented that method. Now, can the "FileServlet" detect if it was called directly by his URL pattern OR if it was called by the other JSP?

I mean, if a non-admin user pastes the call to FileServlet to the browser address bar it should block him.

Comment: The filter will be triggered and to block unwanted users as soon as these users will pass by reference that mapped to given filter in the configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Use servlet filter who check the submiited url and on the basis of the session object it identifies the user role. If it finds the authorized user then it can redirct to the download page